# Parsing a string list with spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm fairly new to bash scripts and this is turning out to be quite a headache. I've come up with some solutions but they're all incredibly dirty...

My objetive is to automatically create a bunch of symlinks using the following code:

```
set repoDir=C:\aRandomPath
set cloudDir=C:\AnotherRandomPath

set filesToLink=(FMODAssets,Resources,Scenes,ScenesTests,Standard Assets,StreamingAssets)

@echo off

ECHO "Will link"
for %%A in %filesToLink% do (
    echo. 
    mklink /J "%repoDir%\Assets\%%A" "%cloudDir%\%%A" 
)
```

Unfortunately this has the side effect of parsing "Standard Assets" as 2 strings: "Standard" AND "Assets". What is the acceptable way of solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from the `set filesToLink`

```
set filesToLink=FMODAssets,Resources,Scenes,ScenesTests,Standard Assets,StreamingAssets
```

Then use

```
for %%A in ("%filesToLink:,=","%") do (
 ECHO(mklink /J "%repoDir%\Assets\%%~A" "%cloudDir%\%%~A"
)
```

which replaces each `,` in the string with `","` and surrounds the entire string with quotes, giving `"sring1","string two","string3"...` Each "quoted element" is assigned to `%%A` in turn and the `~` operator removes the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. Delims=, specifies that only commas are delimiters. %%A is the next token, %%B is the rest of the line. :LinkFiles calls itself until we have processed all tokens.

```
@echo off
set repoDir=C:\aRandomPath
set cloudDir=C:\AnotherRandomPath
set "filesToLink=FMODAssets,Resources,Scenes,ScenesTests,Standard Assets,StreamingAssets"

echo "Will link"
CALL :LinkFiles "%filesToLink%"
goto :eof

:LinkFiles
REM %1=Comma delimited string
for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%A in ("%~1") do (
   echo. 
   mklink /J "%repoDir%\Assets\%%A" "%cloudDir%\%%A"
   CALL :LinkFiles "%%B"
   )
goto :eof
```